# Audio switching internal to headphone for a moment and turning back while playing sound and there is no headphone connection

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have 16.04.1 with latest upgrades. I almost tried everything I can found and reinstalled audio drivers and softwares few times.

While playing video, music or anything on anywhere; sound is crackling and when it happens, all mixer programs are resetting or output port changes to headphone by itself and guess what, there is no headphone connected :P

I know its not a hardware problem but thats all I know. What can I do? Ask me some command output and make up some ideas please..

Comment: *I know its not a hardware problem but thats all I know*. How exactly do you know that? Please add that information to your question.

Comment: I tried other operation systems like Fedora, Antergos and Windows 10. There wasn't any issue. Even on other Linux distros but Ubuntu. So, there is an issue with Ubuntu. I'm not an expert, if there is an expert about this topic he/she will know what can cause that problem. As you see, this comment is equal to "I know its not a hardware problem but thats all I know."